# how do i log in form on magento2.3 home page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I created a login form on the home page of the magento website but I don't know how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

You have to use correct action link in your form declaration like: `<form action="[base_url]/customer/account/loginPost/" ...>`

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me more details please